# VBA Lotus Notes count e-mail attachments

Tags: vba, lotus

Does anybody know how to get number of attachments in Lotus Notes e-mail?
Below approach doesnt work.

```
Set vaItem = Doc.GetFirstItem("Body")

'Loop through all documents in Inbox:
```

m

```
For Each vaAttachment In vaItem.EmbeddedObjects

v = vaItem.EmbeddedObjects(0)
m = Evaluate(v)
MsgBox 

If vaAttachment.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT Then
'Save the attached file into the new folder and remove it from the e-mail.
With vaAttachment
.ExtractFile stPath & vaAttachment.Name
' .Remove

End With
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you passing EmbeddedObects(0) into [NotesSession.Evaluate](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_EVALUATE_METHOD_SESSION_COM.html)? Evaluate takes a string argument, with the string containing a Notes formula. You're passing an EmbeddedObject.

If you want the count, you should be passing the Notes formula [@Attachments](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ATTACHMENTS.html). I.e.,

```
session.Evaluate("@Attachments",Doc)
```

*Note that I'm just assuming you have a variable named 'session' containing your NotesSession object. You didn't show it.*

Comment: It doesnt work. Could you provide more information or sample code?

Comment: I've revised my answer. I forgot that Evaluate requires two arguments. Also, since you are just calling Evaluate, and not calling something like session.Evaluate(), I added that in order to make sure that you are invoking the Lotus Notes objects' Evaluate method, not some other Evaluate method that might be in scope in your code. If your NoteSession is assigned to a different variable name, use that instead.

Comment: Thanks Im going to try it.